# Polar Coordinates in Double Integrals

Tags: calculus

So I have a problem where there is a 2-D region defined as: $$x^2+y^2 \leqslant 2y $$ and I need to evaluate the integral: $$\int\int \! x^2 \, \mathrm{dA} $$

As far as I can tell I need to put this in polar coordinates, but I can't figure out how to go about solving this, let alone drawing a picture. I believe the substitutions are as follows but I'm not entirely sure:

$$x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta), r^2=x^2+y^2, dA=r\,dr\,d\theta$$

So, the first step I need help with is how to graph this. I'm guessing you need to first complete the square to get the full equation: $x^2+y^2-2y+1\leqslant1\Longrightarrow x^2+(y-1)^2\leqslant1^2$ which is the inside of the circular disk.

Beyond that, how do you draw this out freehand to help you get the limits of integration? Since r represents the distance of the radius, I believe its limits are $0 \leqslant r \leqslant 2\sin(\theta)$, but what is $\theta$?

Comment: Draw the circlular disk you arrived at, centered at $(0,1)$. "How much" do you need to go with $\theta$ in order to describe it?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say since it's in the 1st and 2nd quad (I think), it would go from 0 to pi...but maybe that's not right? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: why r depends on $\theta$?

Comment: @tempx - because for each $\theta$ the distance from the origin to the point on the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ in the direction of $\theta$ is different, i.e., depends on $\theta$. In fact, it is $2\sin\theta$, as the OP pointed out.

Comment: @uniquesolution After reading the provided solution I understood your statement. But I have thought to the following new variables $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta +1$. In this case the given constraints become $r^2<=1$ and $0<\theta<2\pi$ which means there is no dependence between $r$ and $\theta$ and the integral becomes $\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{r=1} r^2 \cos^2 \theta \cdot rdr d\theta$. Because of this I asked the dependence of $r$ and $theta$.

Comment: Clearly the disk $\{(r,\theta): r\leq 1, 0<\theta<2\pi\}$ is NOT the given disk $x^2+(y-1)^2\leq 1$ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the area is the circle with radius $1$ centred on $(0,1)$ , which lies enirely in the upper half plane, so indeed as you say in the comments $\theta$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$.

For a given $\theta$ in that range ,$r$ runs from $0$ to what? Well you know from $x^2 + y^2 \le 2y$ that $r^2 \le 2r \sin \theta$ so $r \le 2\sin(\theta)$, as you already gave, which gives us the required upper bound.

So you're left with

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi} \int_{r=0}^{r=2\sin\theta} r^2 \cos^2 \theta \cdot rdr d\theta$$

Comment: Awesome. That just takes a little bit to wrap my head around. Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: As a sanity check: for $\theta=0$ (which actually only hits a point of the circle we indeed get $r=0$ only as boundaries, ditto for $\theta=\pi$ and we have the maximum $r=2$ for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so going up.